# ora- 00936 missing exprssion

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select * from ivoucher 
where date_format(date, '%Y-%m') = 
date_format(now(), '%2016-%Jul');
```

I was trying to run this query but shows missing expression error.

Comment: Are you sure that `now()` and `date_format()` exist in Oracle? Besides, `date` is a reserved word

Comment: Also, please post your table structure, some sample data and desired result

Comment: Where in the [Oracle Manual](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm) did you find `date_format()` or `now()`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you're after rows where the date column (date is a really bad name for a column, since it's a reserved word in Oracle, hence why I've double-quoted it) is in the current month:

```
select *
from   ivoucher 
where  trunc("DATE", 'mm') = trunc(sysdate, 'mm');
```

or maybe you're after specifically something in July 2016? If so:

```
select *
from   ivoucher 
where  trunc("DATE", 'mm') = to_date('01/07/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score -3):

select * from ivoucher where date_format('date', '%Y-%m') = date_format(now(), '%2016-%Jul');

run this cmd to get output.